# Wasn't Dr Marco a sacrifice?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-brotherhood

This is kinda spoilers if you haven't watched all episodes, but my question is:

Wasn't Dr. Marco one of the few sacrifices? Envy didn't want Marco to die, but in the end wasn't used by Father. 
Or did I miss something? Was Marco only captured to create stones?

Comment: You've tagged all three versions of FMA. Which one are you wondering about?

Comment: @kuwaly i'm going to assume not the 2003 series because of the mention of Father

Comment: @Memor-X Makes sense. It's been so long since I've seen the 2003 anime I forgot it didn't have Father.

Comment: Whoops, I actually assumed that Brotherhood was a remake of FMA with the same story. I recently began to watch the 2003 series, haha. 

But yeah, only meant Brotherhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Full Metal Alchemist Wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Tim_Marcoh):

> Knowing this, the Crystal Alchemist attacks Envy using his hidden **transmutation circle** to critically damage the Homunculus' core stone.

Knowing this, he likely has not seen the truth. And as such, would not have been a sacrifice, *right away.*

However, it's not unreasonable to think that the homunculi may have forced him to see the truth once they were ready, (similar to Mustang.)